# Python 2.7.9 PyBrain issue with SciPy

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, pybrain

I just tried installing **SciPy** using [scipy‑0.15.1‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy-stack) 
I have **Python 2.7.9 x64** installed 
I have **wheel installed** 
I have **numpy installed** 
I am working under **Windows7**

The log said that scipy has been successfully installed after running:

```
pip install scipy-0.15.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

The log said that pybrain has been installed succeffully as well:

```
pip install pybrain
```

When I create a python file I can import scipy, but when I try to import pybrain I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\me\Desktop\PROJECT\nn.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import pybrain   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pybrain__init__.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from structure.**init** import *   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure__init__.py", line 2,
>   in 
>       from modules.**init** import *   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\modules__init__.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from gate import GateLayer, DoubleGateLayer, MultiplicationLayer, SwitchLayer   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\modules\gate.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       from pybrain.tools.functions import sigmoid, sigmoidPrime   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pybrain\tools\functions.py", line 4, in
>   
>       from scipy.linalg import inv, det, svd   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg__init__.py", line 161, in
>   
>       from .misc import *   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in
>   
>       from . import blas   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in
>   
>       from scipy.linalg import _fblas ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

trying to

```
import from scipy.linalg import _fblas
```

only gives the same error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\me\Desktop\PROJECT\nn.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from scipy.linalg import _fblas   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg__init__.py", line 161, in
>   
>       from .misc import *   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in
>   
>       from . import blas   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in
>   
>       from scipy.linalg import _fblas ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I reached a conclusion I am missing LAPACK so i build it using [this link](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/index.html#build) The build finished and all tests passed, but the issue is still there... maybe i did not copy the LIB and BIN to the right destination...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall and reinstall.

If you didn't install with sudo the first time, that may be the problem if you're installing for your global Python modules.

You can also try using installs from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy-stack

Comment: thats the same link as the one I provided + uninstalling and re-installing using the same wheel file did no help.

Comment: I'm blind :/ And I also should have realized you're on windows, so I guess my answer is useless.

Comment: No problem I should have specified that I am working on Windows - I thought it was obvious from the file paths